# Why was the USB-A connector not designed to be reversible in the first place?

Tags: usb

Usually a USB-A plug can only be inserted into an USB-A receptacle in one direction. This can be quite frustrating, especially when you need to insert an USB plug blindly.

I recently stumbled upon [a kickstarter for a gadget which is an USB-A plug extension which can be plugged into an USB-A receptacle in any direction](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1255122491/ryo-adapter-never-plug-in-your-usb-the-wrong-way-a).

The design is surprisingly simple: Instead of one slot in the top area it got two slots, one on the top area and one in the bottom area. This makes me wonder why USB-A wasn't designed to be inserted in any orientation in the first place.

Comment: It really is simple.  When first designing the USB-A type connector a conscious decision was made to make it NOT reversible.  Likewise when the USB Type C connector was made the decision was made to make it reversible

Comment: @Ramhound yes, but *why* was that conscious decision made?

Comment: I wasn't on the standards committee that made the decision.  The only reason it wouldn't be reversible is if they decided it shouldn't be.  Your not going to be told the specific reason.  I suggest you word your question in a different way where you are not seeking our opinion on why something was or was not done.

Comment: USB-A was designed by a committee with a socket facing them, in bright light. They never even considered what it would be like round the back of a machine, in the dark. Seen again & again in modern design - striving for ideal usage, with no thought whatsoever for maintenance or real-world conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a reversible connector requires double the number of contact points on the plug, increasing the overall cost of manufacture. It's pretty much as simple as that. The original USB-A and USB-B only required four pins, making them reversible would up the pin count to eight. This in itself isn't a big deal but when you're making these things by the million the extra cost becomes significant.

Comment: Its likely even simpler then that.  They simply didn't even consider making it reversible.  USB at the time was unique of itself.  So while cost considerations of the cable and the connector itself were likely a concern they simply never considered a reversible connector since they didn't really even exist at the time.  As an engineer I certainly wouldn't consider a reversible connector 5 years ago, now that we have them, I might consider that functionality.

Comment: Indeed. Consider what else was common at the time. D-sub connectors for serial and parallel and display, DIN or mini-DIN connectors for keyboard and mouse. None of them are reversible and there were not significant complaints that they were not. I believe that if the USB designers made a mistake, it was more that they did not make the correct orientation more apparent by sight and by touch. If they didn't look (without close inspection) and feel as if they "ought to be" reversible, nobody would be complaining.